# Magento1 createBlock method returns "bool(false)" in livehost

Tags: magento-1.9, fatal-error, custom-block

I've made a module that, in my localhost works fine.. The block shows up and ok, but in "livehost" the block don't appear, so I created a controller to make some tests and see what is the problem.

```
public function minhaactionAction(){
    $this->loadLayout();
    $block = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('slideproducts/slideproducts');
    var_dump($block);
    $block->setTemplate('slideproducts/slideproducts.phtml');
    $this->getLayout()->getBlock('content')->append($block);
    $this->renderLayout();
}
```

In my localhost the block continue, but in site var_dump($block); returns bool(false). I search for a light by days and nothing yet, I hope so someone can help me to solve this problem.

If I use the $block->setTemplate('...'); it gives an error:

> "**Fatal error:** Call to a member function setTemplate() on boolean in /home/httpd/htdocs/..."

Obviously, its because the createBlock function returns false.

config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0">
<config>
<modules>
    <AndersonGustavo_SlideProducts>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </AndersonGustavo_SlideProducts>
</modules>
<frontend>
    <routers>
        <andersongustavo_slideproducts>
            <use>standard</use>
            <args>
                <module>AndersonGustavo_SlideProducts</module>
                <frontName>teste</frontName>
            </args>
        </andersongustavo_slideproducts>
    </routers>
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <AndersonGustavo_SlideProducts>
                <file>slideproducts.xml</file>
            </AndersonGustavo_SlideProducts>
        </updates>
    </layout>
</frontend>
<global>
    <models>
        <slideproducts>
            <class>AndersonGustavo_SlideProducts_Model_System_Config_Source</class>
        </slideproducts>
    </models>
    <blocks>
        <slideproducts>
            <class>AndersonGustavo_SlideProducts_Block</class>
        </slideproducts>
    </blocks>
    <helpers>
        <slideproducts>
            <class>AndersonGustavo_SlideProducts_Helper</class>
        </slideproducts>
    </helpers>
</global>
```

SlideProducts.php

```
class AndersonGustavo_SlideProducts_Block_SlideProducts extends Mage_Core_Block_Template {

public function __construct(array $args)
{
    $this->setTemplate('slideproducts/slideproducts.phtml');
}

public function isEnabled(){
    return Mage::getStoreConfig('andersongustavo/category/enabled');
}

private function getCategories(){
    return Mage::getStoreConfig('andersongustavo/category/category_groups');
}

public function getHeader(){
    return Mage::getStoreConfig('andersongustavo/category/header');
}

public function getCategoriesId(){
    $enabledCategories = explode(',',$this->getCategories());
    return $enabledCategories;
}

public function getCategoryProducts($enabledCategoryId){
    $categoryProducts = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')
                                    ->load($enabledCategoryId)
                                    ->getProductCollection()
                                    ->addAttributeToSelect("*")
                                    ->addAttributeToFilter('status',1);
    return $categoryProducts;
}

public function getProductImage($id){
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($id);

    foreach ($product->getMediaGalleryImages() as $image){
        return $image->getUrl();
    }
}
}
```

exception.log

```
exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Tipo de bloco inválido: AndersonGustavo_SlideProducts_Block_Slideproducts' in /home/httpd/htdocs/ovaralbr/public/app/Mage.php:595
Stack trace:
#0 /home/httpd/htdocs/ovaralbr/public/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(495): Mage::throwException('Tipo de bloco i...')
#1 /home/httpd/htdocs/ovaralbr/public/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(437): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_getBlockInstance('slideproducts/s...', Array)
#2 /home/httpd/htdocs/ovaralbr/public/app/code/local/AndersonGustavo/SlideProducts/controllers/IndexController.php(24): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('slideproducts/s...')
#3 /home/httpd/htdocs/ovaralbr/public/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): AndersonGustavo_SlideProducts_IndexController->minhaactionAction()
#4 /home/httpd/htdocs/ovaralbr/public/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('minhaaction')
#5 /home/httpd/htdocs/ovaralbr/public/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#6 /home/httpd/htdocs/ovaralbr/public/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(365): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#7 /home/httpd/htdocs/ovaralbr/public/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#8 /home/httpd/htdocs/ovaralbr/public/index.php(93): Mage::run('', 'store')
#9 {main}
```

(Tipo de bloco inválido:) is, Invalid block type

Comment: can you please paste your block class as well?

Comment: Ok! I paste the block class. Do you think, it's necessary to paste my template .phtml file too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that versions of your Magento in localhost and live versions are different.

After Magento version 1.9.1, Magento introduced a new feature of block permissions.

Now if you are introducing a new block class in Magento system, you need to allow it from:

**`System -> Permissions -> Blocks`**

Click add new block where block name **`slideproducts/slideproducts`** and **`isAllowed -> Yes`**

Now save. Clear cache. Hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: Yes, the versions are different.. but, my localhost is 1.9.3.1 and the livehost is 1.9.2.2. Unfortunately the problem continues.

Comment: Have you done what I have written in my answer? Please enable Magento's log from **`System -> Configuration -> Advanced (Developer) -> Log Settings`** and then check /var/log folder after reloading page.

Comment: Yep.. I'll edit the post and paste the log

Comment: In the exception.log I could see that the magento is searching for a Slideproducts.php, but the file's name is SlideProducts.php.. Do you know why, and how can I make magento search for the file in camel case.. by the way, you solve my problem!!! I'm very grateful, you save the day.. or bette..r the week =P Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Your action code should be

```
public function minhaactionAction()
{
    $this->loadLayout();
    $block = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('slideproducts/slideproducts');
    var_dump($block);
    $block->setTemplate('slideproducts/slideproducts.phtml');
    $this->getLayout()->getBlock('content')->append($block);
    $this->renderLayout();
}
```

Comment: Sorry, my bad!!!! I forgot to paste this code line, have a lot of comment lines here.. I'll edit my question post and thank you.

Comment: Did you clear cache? It works fine here.

Comment: Yes, I clear all caches and disabled them.